# SQL query to find name with max price purchase made?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, `customers` and `purchases`. `Purchases` has a `total_price` column and foreign key `cid` referencing `customers.cid`. I need to select names of customers (came) who made the highest total_price purchase.

I'm trying this

```
select 
    cname 
from 
    customers c 
where exists
    (select pid 
     from purchases p 
     where total_price in (select max(total_price) 
                           from purchases p 
                           where max(total_price) = total_price 
                             and p.cid = c.cid))
```

I get the error, group function is not allowed here -->

```
where max(total_price) = total_price
```

Please help me out

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just sum up the totals for each customer and then order it by highest totals like so:

```
select cname, sum(total_price) as totals
from customers c
inner join purchases p
  on c.cid = p.cid
group by cname
order by totals desc
limit 1
```

Here's an example with MySQL database: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/133fa/1

I have an example with Oracle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9d786/4

```
with 
totals as
(
  select cid, sum(total_price) as totals
  from purchases
  group by cid
), 
highest as (
  select max(totals) as highest from totals
)
select cname
from customers c
inner join totals t on c.cid = t.cid
inner join highest h on t.totals = h.highest
```

Comment: "limit 1" = sqlite syntax?!

Comment: Since OP didn't mention the database server used, I chose to use `limit` that is supported by sqlite, MySQL, PostgreSQL etc. OP can improvise using this answer if database doesn't support limit.

Comment: it's saying error for limit 1, sql command not ended properly. will it give me  multiple same highest total_price values too?

Comment: What database server are you using @SamKeith? Is it Oracle, SQL Server or something else? And what what version?

Comment: Perfect. Try out the query I added (along with SQLFiddle example) and see how it works for you.

Comment: It works, thanks, will it also return multiple values of same total_price ? @zedfoxus

Comment: Yes, it will. Check out the [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9d786/4). In that example I have multiple people with same total price.

Comment: @SamKeith please make sure you put closure to your question by marking any one of the answers as accepted. I noticed that one more question that you asked on StackOverflow may be waiting for your acceptance.

Comment: So I used this query select purchasenum from purchases where total_price>=
(select total_price from purchases where cid='XYZ' and rownum=1) , I get the values but how can I exclude ABC from the result? @RYoda  and zedfoxus

Comment: @zedfoxus I'll make sure of that :) thank you, just a bit swamped right now

Comment: You could do `select purchasenum from purchases where total_price>= (select total_price from purchases where cid='XYZ' and rownum=1) and purchasenum <> 'ABC'`. If that doesn't work, can you please add a new question to StackOverflow after closing out this question? In your new question, add example of your data and expected results. Tag your question with Oracle as the RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

You can also store the highest purchase for each customer in a temporaly table(In SQL Server, for instance):

```
SELECT c.cid, cname, max(total_price) as total
into #temp_customers_highest_purchase
FROM customers c
JOIN purchases p on c.cid = p.cid
group by c.cid, cname
```

After that you can select the customer with the highest total_price:

```
select cname, total 
from #temp_customers_highest_purchase tmp
join customer c on c.cid = tmp.cid
```

This approach could hep with performance since you are not using subqueries.

If you are not using SQL Server you can try using WITH clausule, which is very helpful regarding to performance.

```
WITH subquery AS (
    SELECT c.cid, cname, max(total_price) as total
    FROM customers c
    JOIN purchases p on c.cid = p.cid
    group by c.cid, cname)
SELECT total from subquery sb WHERE sb.cid = 'id you want'
```

Comment: I'm using oracle on unix server, I tried to store values in #temporary_table, it showed # is invalid character, do I need to make a new table by the name of  temporary_table before executing this or will the temp table be created automatically by executing your mentioned query?

Comment: SQL Server creates the #temp_customers_highest_purchase automatically... I don't know if Oracle does... anyway you can try creating the temporaly table or just using the WITH query...

Answer (score 0):

To select the names with the top 10 "total_price"s enter (assuming you are using Microsoft SQL Server - other SQL servers provide similar features as "top"):

```
SELECT TOP 10 cname FROM customers c
INNER JOIN purchases p on c.cid = p.cid
order by p.total_price DESC
```

Replace "10" with any number you want and take care about having indexes on the join and order colums if you have a lot of data...

If you have more than 10 clients with the same total_price you will not see all of them.

----------- Edit: To see all clients in case of more than on client having the highest total_price (but without duplicating one client if he has two purchases with the same [highest] total_price: -----------

```
SELECT DISTINCT cname FROM customers c
INNER JOIN purchases p ON c.cid = p.cid
WHERE p.total_price =
(SELECT MAX( p2.total_price ) FROM purchases p2)
```

Comment: I just need the name of customer with highest purchase(total_price) value.

Comment: Only your best client? Use "top 1" then... But in fact: If several customers have the same total_price you will get only the first one and I think you will see all of them...!?

Comment: I tried SELECT TOP 1 cname FROM customers c
INNER JOIN purchases p on c.cid = p.cid
order by p.total_price DESC , but it gives an error "FROM keyword not found where expected". And yes I need to see all of them if they have same total_price

Comment: Which SQL server are you using?

Comment: I'm using the university's Oracle server running on unix server @R Yoda

Comment: OK so the "TOP 10" syntax does not work. You should use Oracle's "WHERE ROWNUM <= 10" instead...

Comment: Thanks man, it works, let me use it without aggregate function(where rownum<=) for top 1 @R Yoda

Comment: can I do something like this, I need to find purchases made that have higher total_price than the highest total_price of a customer abc,first selecting purchases made my abc and then rownum=1 and somehow compare it with purchases made  by other members?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    Name, 
    (select sum(total_price) from purchases where cid=customers.cid) as HighestTotalPrice 
from 
    customers
```